# How to bring bootstrap 3 panels into bootstrap 2 website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I searched alot but couldn't find anything! How can I do it? Is there any library or something like that or any *fix*?

Comment: Open bootstrap's css and copy all related css to 2?

Comment: Customize/compile bootstrap 3 with only panels. After that check if it conflicts with bootstrap 2 css/js in the manual and Customize/compile bootstrap 2 without the conflicting components. Copy css from bootstrap 3 to bootstrap 2 file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Panels in Bootstrap 3 are only construct with CSS. You will find the code in less/panels.less

To make it yourself easy: open panels.less an add the line below at the top of this file:

```
@import "variables.less";
@import "mixins.less";
```

Compile this file with any less compiler to css. Copy the result in your BS2 document below the Bootstrap's CSS.

See: http://bootply.com/79222

The panel header (h3) got a line-height of 40px from the BS2 Css, ao add one extra line of css to undo this: `.panel-heading > h3 {line-height:20px;}`.

You could also copy the panels.less to your Twitter's Bootstrap 2 less and import it in bootstrap.less and compile this. In this case copy the panel variables from variables.less to variables.less of Bootstrap 2 at least.